# Spring's @DateTimeFormat produces a Date object with the previous day

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc

I've got a requestParam that takes in a date (ie. 2017-01-24T06:00:00.000Z).

I'm using DateTimeFormat to format it into a date to pass into my controller.

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date myDate
```

but when I print myDate to my console I get "Mon Jan 23, 18:00:00 CST 2017", but in my example above it should be Jan 24th. Why is it changing my date back 1 day?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several things at play here.

First, Spring's [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html), when annotating a `java.util.Date` field or parameter, [uses a `SimpleDateFormat` with its timezone set to `UTC`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/datetime/DateFormatter.java#L180).

Second, you've used [`DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE) which represents

> The most common ISO Date Format `yyyy-MM-dd`, e.g. "2000-10-31".

In other words, it does not consider any timezone information in your date string (this doesn't really matter because your date string was rooted at Zulu anyway).

Third, you've provided a date string where everything but the `iso` pattern gets ignored. The `SimpleDateFormat` only cares about the `2017-01-24` part.

Since the timezone is set to `UTC`, it considers the `2017-01-24` date as being rooted at UTC, at midnight, zero'ed hours, minutes, and seconds.

Finally, since your system's default time zone is Central Standard Time, ie. UTC-6), when you call [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) on the `Date` object, it'll return a `String` that is formatted with that time zone, ie. 6 hours before midnight.

---

Remember also that a `Date` has no concept of a timezone. It is a timestamp.

---

To "fix" this, construct your [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern--) with an appropriate `pattern` that interprets both time and time zone. I would use

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX") Date myDate
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I have one more question. Can I know what's the difference between 'Z' and 'X'? Will it also works with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`?

Comment: @wonsuc For `Date`, it uses the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern characters that are defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). That explains their purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed I didn't read the comment of `DateTimeFormat` class carefully. It says `The most common ISO DateTime Format {@code yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}, e.g. "2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00".` Now I understand why I need to use 'X' :)

Answer (score 2):

For me it works without `@JsonFormat` when `json` has the pattern 'yyyy-mm-dd'

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private LocalDate startDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure the time zone in general you can use the following:

```
 spring.jackson.time-zone=EST
```

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) indicates: "Time zone used when formatting dates. For instance, 'America/Los_Angeles' or 'GMT+10'".

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Tried and tested

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private LocalDate startDate;
```